# When a C-program with empy main body executes, would it only involves user-mode?

Tags: operating-system, kernel-mode, usermode

Typically, when a program starts executing, it begins in user-mode and then depending on the body of the code, if required enters kernel/system mode, and eventually exits in the user-mode where it exits legitimately. But consider the following C program, `prog1.c`:

```
void main()
{ 
 //empty bodied prog1.c
}
```

I am of the opinion that this program/process only runs in user-mode alone. Particularly, I am also of the opinion that this program/process would never involve any kernel-mode. But want to know experts' opinions.

Thanks,
SS

Comment: Every function which has to return hides an exit system call, so yeah, behind the scenes you are going through kernel mode even if you as a user didn't trigger it.

Comment: The OS will do all sorts of things in kernel-mode to setup the process before main() executes, and more to cleanup the process after main() returns.